# JOIN tables in Access

Tags: ms-access, join

I have two tables in Microsoft Access

**Table_1**

```
id_customer,id_city,city,qty
123,045,New York,45
```

**Table_2**

```
id,name
12345,Audy
54321,Steve
```

**Query in Ms. Access**

```
SELECT * FROM  table_1 RIGHT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id_customer&MID(table_1.id_city,2,2)=table_2.id;
```

**Error :**

```
JOIN expression not supported
```

please correct my query and thanks before

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing some spacing.  Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 AS t1
  RIGHT JOIN table_2 AS t2
  ON ((t1.id_customer & MID(t1.id_city, 2, 2)) = t2.id)
```